# 553-SPF (Sender Policy Framework) domain authentication

Tags: php

```
chimto@businessname.com
host cluster5.eu.messagelabs.com [46.226.52.103]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    553-SPF (Sender Policy Framework) domain authentication
    553-fail. Refer to the Troubleshooting page at
    553-https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?legacyId
    553 =3DTECH246726 for more information. (#5.7.1)
Reporting-MTA: dns; vomchimto2.mailcluster.com.au
```

My email inbox on this hosting is blocked!
Someone please help me!
Still can't figure out how to fix this!!! :(

1. Is it the fault of my hosting, or the client's hosting blocking "@ businessname.com" block me?
2. I still want hosting to send email without using SMTP

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This message says the remote server blocked you from sending this mail because the the domain(DNS) entries say you are not allowed to send mails for this domain(businessname.com). Could be also that the server you are sending this to is requiring spf dns records. As i can see there is no spf entry for businessname.com.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework
"SPF allows the receiving mail server to check during mail delivery that a mail claiming to come from a specific domain is submitted by an IP address authorized by that domain's administrators.[3] The list of authorized sending hosts and IP addresses for a domain is published in the DNS records for that domain."